# Show Availability Stock Status in Email Woocommerce

Tags: wordpress

Is it possible to show the stock status as "In Stock" "Pre-Order" in new order mails?

These codes help me show the SKU in Mail, but I could not create the stock status by changing it.

```
/**
 * Adds SKUs and product images to WooCommerce order emails
 */
function sww_add_sku_to_wc_emails( $args ) {
  
    $args['show_sku'] = true;
    return $args;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_items_args', 'sww_add_sku_to_wc_emails' );
```

Answer (score 0):

You can show the stock status of the products via the `woocommerce_display_item_meta` hook, for more information: https://woocommerce.github.io/code-reference/files/woocommerce-includes-wc-template-functions.html#source-view.3290

Here is the code for your case:

```
add_filter( 'woocommerce_display_item_meta', 'show_stock_status_in_email', 10, 3 );
function show_stock_status_in_email( $html, $item, $args ) {
    // gets the product object
    $product = $item->get_product();
    // gets stock status product
    $stock_status = $product->get_stock_status();
    // show it after the product name
    $html .= '<p style="margin:0;"><strong>(' . $stock_status . ')</strong></p>';
    return $html;
}
```

The result will be the following:

[image]

The code has been tested and works. Add it in your theme's functions.php file.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add custom message instead of the standard "outofstock" and "instock" status, you can use:

```
/** Add custom stock message to order emails - 14-02-2022 **/
add_action( 'woocommerce_order_item_meta_end', 'rt_order_item_meta_end', 10, 4 );
function rt_order_item_meta_end( $item_id, $item, $order, $plain_text ) {
  $product = $item->get_product();
  // if product is on backorder and backorder is allowed (adjust accordingly to your shop setup)
  if ( $product->backorders_require_notification() && $product->is_on_backorder( $item['quantity'] ) ) {
    echo '<p style="color:#ff5349; font-size:12px;">Not in stock</p>';
  }
  // else do this
  else {
    echo '<p style="color:#83b735; font-size:12px;">In stock</p>';
  }
}
```

Code should be added to function.php of your active theme. At best in the function.php of your child theme.